# Error in mist : exceed block gas limit

Tags: contract-deployment, private-blockchain, mist, gas-limit

I am trying to deploy a smart contract in private network using mist, but when I deploy my contract and provide transaction fee as 0.04 ether it throws error as exceeding block gas limit. Here is the pic

[image]

What fee should I provide for proper deployment?

This is my contract-

```
    pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
    contract Greet
    {
  string message;
  constructor() public
  {
    message = "I'm ready!";

}
function setgreetings(string _message)public
{
    message = _message;

}
function getgreetings()public constant returns(string)
{
    return message;
}
}
```

my blockchain gas limit is -

```
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
```

Comment: It might be that your call generates an error. Without the source code is hard to say anything, verify the `requires` are satisfied. Another possibility is that your blockchain has a low block gas limit.

Comment: I was able to deploy my contract successfully when I provide zero gas fee. How did that happen? @Ismael

Comment: Without more details is hard to say exactly what is going on. Perhaps your account doesn't have enough ether to pay for the transaction so setting the gas price to 0 will allow it to be processed.